# How to remove seconds before the first full minute

Tags: r, aggregate, mean, lubridate

I currently have second by second data from an accelerometer that I need to average by the minute (average 60 seconds together). The issue is that I have data at the beginning and end of the first and last minute that are not a whole minute.  I want to remove those seconds so when I average by the minute, it always starts and stops on the minute.  My data is also multiple participants stacked on top of each other so I would need to do this by id.  An example of how my data is laid out is below:

```
ID    Timestamp
*1     2017-03-15 10:29:58
1     2017-03-15 10:29:59*
1     2017-03-15 10:30:00
1     2017-03-15 10:30:01
...
*1     2017-03-15 12:48:00*
*1     2017-03-15 12:48:01*
*1     2017-03-15 12:48:02*
*2     2017-04-01 11:19:59*
2      2017-03-15 11:20:00
```

etc.

Hopefully I can do this where I can eliminate the italicized rows for each ID so I only have whole minutes for each person. (I have about 80-95 ids per dataframe). This will allow me to aggregate by the whole minute.

If there is an easier way to average the values on the whole minute that would not require me to remove rows, that may be easier.

Comment: Extract minute into its own column, group by minute (and ID), filter out groups with less than 60 observations.

Comment: If your data is POSIXct, you can use round.POSIXt() or trunc.POSIXt() to round it to the closest whole minute or to the closest whole minute under it (respectively). Afterwards, you can run operations grouped on the whole minute using whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged this with `lubridate`, here is a `lubridate`/`tidyverse` solution. (If I understood your question correctly.)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id,            ~timestamp,
  1, "2017-03-15 10:29:58",
  1, "2017-03-15 10:29:59",
  1, "2017-03-15 10:30:00",
  1, "2017-03-15 10:30:01",
  1, "2017-03-15 12:48:00",
  1, "2017-03-15 12:48:01",
  1, "2017-03-15 12:48:02",
  2, "2017-04-01 11:19:59",
  2, "2017-03-15 11:20:00"
    ) %>%
  mutate(
    timestamp = as_datetime(timestamp),
    x = rnorm(n())                    # some var you want aggregate
  )
```

If you just want to keep observations that are "whole minute", as you call it, then keep the observations with time stamps that are the same when floored by minute.

```
df %>%
  filter(timestamp == floor_date(timestamp, "minute"))
```

If you don't have observations matching exactly the floored time stamp, but you want to keep the observations that are closest to the "whole minute", then you can arrange them by timestamp and keep the first one within each minute.

```
df %>%
  arrange(timestamp) %>%
  mutate(min = floor_date(timestamp, "minute")) %>%
  group_by(min, id) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

If you want to aggregate some variable x by minute, say, take the mean, then group by a floored time stamp.

```
df %>%
  mutate(min = floor_date(timestamp, "minute")) %>%
  group_by(min, id) %>%
  summarize(mean_var = mean(var)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `lubridate`  and `tidyverse` approach using Gregor's comment suggestion. Since we expect whole minute observations to have 60 observations, we can just filter out those that don't have 60. I create a span slightly longer than a minute to illustrate. If you have a timespan longer than an hour (so minutes repeat), just make an hour column too with `hour()` and group on that as well.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
tbl <- tibble(
  time = ymd_hms("2017-03-15 10:29:57") + 1:66
)
head(tbl)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 1
#>   time               
#>   <dttm>             
#> 1 2017-03-15 10:29:58
#> 2 2017-03-15 10:29:59
#> 3 2017-03-15 10:30:00
#> 4 2017-03-15 10:30:01
#> 5 2017-03-15 10:30:02
#> 6 2017-03-15 10:30:03
tail(tbl)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 1
#>   time               
#>   <dttm>             
#> 1 2017-03-15 10:30:58
#> 2 2017-03-15 10:30:59
#> 3 2017-03-15 10:31:00
#> 4 2017-03-15 10:31:01
#> 5 2017-03-15 10:31:02
#> 6 2017-03-15 10:31:03
tbl %>%
  mutate(minute = minute(time)) %>%
  group_by(minute) %>%
  filter(n() == 60)
#> # A tibble: 60 x 2
#> # Groups:   minute [1]
#>    time                minute
#>    <dttm>               <int>
#>  1 2017-03-15 10:30:00     30
#>  2 2017-03-15 10:30:01     30
#>  3 2017-03-15 10:30:02     30
#>  4 2017-03-15 10:30:03     30
#>  5 2017-03-15 10:30:04     30
#>  6 2017-03-15 10:30:05     30
#>  7 2017-03-15 10:30:06     30
#>  8 2017-03-15 10:30:07     30
#>  9 2017-03-15 10:30:08     30
#> 10 2017-03-15 10:30:09     30
#> # ... with 50 more rows
```

Created on 2018-05-09 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).